# Sqlite FTS5 initial token query syntax?

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, fts5

I have set up FTS5 (full-text search) with virtual tables in sqlite. MATCH queries are working except it always throws a syntax error on initial token queries.

For example: `SELECT * FROM fts_article WHERE fts_article MATCH '^suo'` throws

```
Error calling sqlite3_step (1: fts5: syntax error near "^") rs
```

I've tried all the [syntax variations](https://sqlite.org/fts5.html#carrotq) listed in the docs, getting the same error.

(In production code I will be using bound parameters, and I've tried it that way also.)

UPDATE: Some additional context: I am using the sqlite baked into libsqlcipher-ios.a from SQLCipher. And I am running my sql through FMDB. I have tried calling the sqlite api directly. In that case, the error seems to go away but I'm not seeing the results I expect. Still investigating ...

Comment: While SQLite version? Can you try the latest?

Comment: Were you able to fix this? If so, what was the problem?

Comment: I have the same problem, had u found any solution?